# Random color: return a function for the fill attribute

Tags: d3.js, layout, pack

I am creating the data for a pack layout dynamically with a for loop. 
I would like the color of the circle to be random. 
My code return the actual function for the fill attribute:

```
<circle cx="532.0508075688773" cy="219.6152422706632" r="46.41016151377546" fill="function () {
                    return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 +",100%,50%)"
                    }" name="1"></circle>
```

How can change my code so it's the return of the function that is passed to the fill attribute?

The relevant part of how the data use to create the rootnode

```
...
for (var j=0;j<10;j++){
    child = {}; 
    child["name"]= +j;
    child["value"]=2;
    child["fill"]=function() {
        return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)";
        };
...
```

This is how I create the circle

```
d3.select('svg g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(rootNode.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    ...
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.data.fill; })
```

Comment: Instead of returning the function with return `d.date.fill`, can you note return the result of the function with `return d.data.fill()` ?

Comment: @AndrewReid Instead of returning the result of the function (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6ev09chw/) the best idea is just use the value itself as the datum. Storing functions as data is not a good practice.

Comment: Agreed, the comment was more because I was unsure that I read the question correctly for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting a function as the datum of the node...

```
child["fill"] = function() {
    return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ", 100%, 50%)";
};
```

... just set the value itself:

```
child["fill"] = "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ", 100%, 50%)";
```

Here is a basic demo following the same principle:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var data = [{
  name: "foo",
  fill: "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  fill: "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  fill: "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"
}];
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) {
    return 50 + 100 * i
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.fill
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

However, I'd say that storing functions (`Math.random()` is a function) in the data is not a good (or a standard) practice.

Instead of that, why don't you store the lightness and the saturation themselves? Then, you can use the `Math.random()` directly in the callback:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + "," + d.saturation + "," + d.lightness + ")"
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var data = [{
  name: "foo",
  saturation: "100%",
  lightness: "50%"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  saturation: "40%",
  lightness: "30%"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  saturation: "100%",
  lightness: "80%"
}];
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) {
    return 50 + 50 * i
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + "," + d.saturation + "," + d.lightness + ")"
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I store the color in the data because, some circle will have a random color while other do not. So in my data, some circles have the fill value as `"hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ", 100%, 50%)";`  while others have a plain color value like `red`. In that case do you think I can still store the function in my data? If not, should I proceed with a css class style?

Comment: You can just check for null or undefined.